# Factory Girl/specific association for Rspec model test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to do this, in spec/models/user_role.spec:

```
role_trainer = FactoryGirl.create(:role_trainer)
user_role = FactoryGirl.build(:user_role, :role => role_trainer)
```

where I want to specify the specific "role_trainer" in spec/factories/roles.rb:

```
factory :role_trainer, parent: :role do |f|
  f.name "trainer"
end
```

and then for spec/factories/role_spec.rb, I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_role do
    user
    role
  end
end
```

and the models are:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
```

That is, in words, I want to determine the "role" of the "user role" that is going to be created.
However, when I do this, I do not find that the "role_trainer" was used as the role, for the user_role. (Instead, a user_role gets created by the build statement (at the top) which has nothing to do with "trainer".) What is wrong with my setup?

Another way to ask it - I need to add multiple roles to a single user, by creating multiple user_roles. How can I specify the input user, to the FactoryGirl build?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :role_trainer do
        name 'Trainer'
    end
end
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. But this just causes an unregistered factory for role_trainer. Here's another way to think about this problem. I need to be able to add multiple roles to a single user. I can't do that if I can't specify the user associated with the user_role. Like you focused on, I suspect it is my FactoryGirl setup for user_role, somehow.